# How do you run an executable file located in the assets folder in android studio when the target SDK version is 29 or higher?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have the following function in my android studio app:

```
public void startStockfish() {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        // Open Stockfish binary from assets folder
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("x86/stockfish_nosimd");
        System.out.println("binary opened from assets folder");

        // Create a temporary file to copy Stockfish binary
        File stockfishFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "stockfish");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(stockfishFile);
        System.out.println("temporary file created");

        // Copy Stockfish binary to a temporary file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        System.out.println("stockfish binary copied");

        // Close streams
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println("streams closed");

        // Set executable permission for the file
        stockfishFile.setExecutable(true);
        System.out.println("permissions set");

        // Start Stockfish process using the copied file
        stockfishProcess = new ProcessBuilder(stockfishFile.getAbsolutePath()).start();
        System.out.println("process started");

        // Initialize input and output streams
        stockfishInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stockfishProcess.getInputStream()));
        stockfishOutput = new OutputStreamWriter(stockfishProcess.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("I/O initialized");

        // Send 'uci' command to Stockfish
        sendCommandToStockfish("uci");
        System.out.println("stockfish was successful");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("stockfish is broken");
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle exceptions (file not found, etc.) accordingly
    }
}
```

The function works exactly as expected as long as the sdk version is 28, but when changing to 29, I recieve the following permissions error:

> Cannot run program
> "/data/user/0/com.example.chessrepertoiremanager/cache/stockfish":
> error=13, Permission denied

The error is a result of trying to run the line:

`stockfishProcess = new ProcessBuilder(stockfishFile.getAbsolutePath()).start();`

After trying to debug using online searches as well as ChatGPT, I have done the following:

1. added permissions to my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. added the following provider block to manifest:

```
<provider
     android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
     android:authorities="com.example.chessrepertoiremanager.fileprovider"
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

3. added the following provider_paths.xml file to my res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="cache_files"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

I have also tried a variety of other things based on chatgpt recommendations, but they only made matters worse. None of my internet searches have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation for Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission):

> Execution of files from the writable app home directory is a [W^X violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX). Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's APK file.

In this case, an asset does not count as "embedded within an app's APK file". You need to see if anyone has created a library out of [Stockfish](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish) that you can link to more conventionally using the NDK.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear about the file itself. This is an .so file that is compiled via a .mk from the c++ source code (stockfish is fully open source) at build time. The resulting .so file is saved into the asset folder, which is where it is first referenced in the java code above.

Comment: @BrentUnderwood: Last I checked, `.so` files are not executables. They are libraries, that you would use with the NDK.